# How does one achieve a square spiral like the the Ulam spiral in Netlogo?

Tags: primes, netlogo, spiral

I spent the morning trying to find an easy function (x,y) -> n that would number the patches like this

[image]

I was not successful. Do any of Y'all have any experience or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on it:

```
patches-own [ n ]

to setup
  clear-all
  resize-world -4 4 -4 4 ; so it looks better, but use any size you like...
  create-turtles 1 [
    set heading 180
    foreach n-values count patches [ ? + 1 ] [
      set n ?
      if [ n = 0 ] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 [ left 90 ]
      fd 1
    ]
    die
  ]
  ask patches [ set plabel n ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Funny you should ask I also spent the morning doing the same thing. There is a function that uses the floor function but I remembered that this is netlogo
so I made a turtle do it for me.

with this procedure

```
to spin
 let k 1
  set t t + 1
  repeat 2
  [
   lt 90
   repeat t [fd 1 ask patch-here [set n k set k k + 1]]
  ]
end
```

and this code in the start up.

```
 crt 1 [
    set heading 0
    repeat 41 [spin]
    die
    ]
```

and of course

```
patches-own [n]
```

to call them in n order use

```
foreach sort-on [n] patches ask ? [ "the stuff you want them to do" ]
```